# Problem in installing Matex

Tags: installation, matex

I am using Mathematica 12.0, and I want to install Matex. According to this page
https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX

only writing the code  `ResourceFunction["MaTeXInstall"][]` should work, but I get this error

[image]

I have downloaded "MaTeX-1.7.8.paclet" and put it in drive C, but the problem still persists.

Can someone please guide me where I am going wrong? I am not good at installing software and so on, maybe it is so simple.

Comment: Try using the [`Wolfram Function Repository`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MaTeXInstall/) to install. Also, this page states that "MaTeX requires Ghostscript and a TeX system to be installed." Are they?

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks. Yes, they are installed.